# how can i append selected row data in another table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

what my task is I am using a table with two different conditions like in the first table whatever data coming I will show that in the first table and in the second table whatever row I select in the first table that I want to show in the second table as the second table I called select summary so my task is in the first table whatever row I selected in need to how that row in the second table I am using same table component for this for better you can see CodeSandBox link

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  makeStyles,
  CardContent,
  Card,
  Box
} from "@material-ui/core";
import EnhancedTable from "./EnhancedTable";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2, 2),
  },
  formGrid: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  cardColor: {
    borderColor: "#0bb7a7",
  },
  
}));


function AddToExclusionList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [sanctionsList, setSanctionsList] = useState([]);
  const updateListsRow = ({ index, value, row }, listType) => {
    switch (listType) {
      case "sanctions":
        setSanctionsList((prevState) => {
          prevState[index].status = value;
          return [...prevState];
        });
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        <Card className={classes.cardColor} variant="outlined">
          <CardContent>
              <>
                <EnhancedTable
                  show={true}
                  step="first"
                />
              </>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Box mt={3}></Box>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        <Card className={classes.cardColor} variant="outlined">
          <CardContent>
              <>
                <h3>summary table</h3>
                <EnhancedTable 
                checkboxToggle={(rowDetails) => {
                  updateListsRow(rowDetails, "sanctions");
                }}
                />
              </>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default AddToExclusionList;
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-bird-s8ix8?file=/src/App.js:0-1476)

Comment: Can you please add punctuation to your text so it's readable?

Comment: ok I am updating in code sandbox

Comment: @devdeveloper Would you like to filter second table based on first table's selected row?

Comment: like what i select in first table that i need to show in second summay table

Comment: in the first table, I am getting all data or then whatever I select in the first table only that selected row I need to show in the second table

Comment: @ChrisG updated some readable formate

Comment: @MajidM. are you got it what i am saying

Comment: @devdeveloper Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've achieved your goal very weird! Anyway, based on your code in `codesandbox`. You need to add a state to `AddToExclusionList` component, like this:

```
  const [newRows, setNewRows] = useState([]);
  const setSummaryRows = (selectedRows) => {
    const copy = [...rows];
    const filteredRows = copy.filter((x) => selectedRows.includes(x.name));
    setNewRows(filteredRows);
  };
```

We need the mentioned state to update the summary table's rows.
Also add `rows` and `setNewRows` prop to `EnhancedTable` and give it rows from out of the component. In addition move `rows` and `createData` to `App.js`. So you should use `EnhancedTable` in `App.js` same as bellow:

```
<Grid className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        <Card className={classes.cardColor} variant="outlined">
          <CardContent>
            <>
              <h3>first table</h3>
              <EnhancedTable
                // passing data for rendering table according condition
                step="first"
                rows={rows}
                setNewRows={(selected) => {
                  setSummaryRows(selected);
                }}
              />
            </>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Box mt={3}></Box>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        <Card className={classes.cardColor} variant="outlined">
          <CardContent>
            <>
              <h3>summary table</h3>
              <EnhancedTable
                // trying to pasing selected data
                rows={newRows}
                setNewRows={() => {}}
              />
            </>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And the last part is using `useEffect` based on `selected` in `EnhancedTable` component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewRows(selected);
  }, [selected]);
```

[image: Edit dazzling-bohr-srnh3]